# Acceleration structure for AABBs with many overlaps

Tags: collision-detection, aabb

I have large number of AABB in 2D. They are created around complex polygons and I use them as pre-test before real point in polygon test (which is expensive).

I was thinking of creating acceleration structure, since testing hunderds of AABB is not ideal even with a simple point-in-AABB test.

What acceleration structure is considered best for this, since AABBs may overlap a lot (however, polygons do not). See the picture with a simple small example.

[image]

I was looking at BVH, but for them overlaps should be minimal. Another solution are kD-trees, however the overlaps are problem as well. QuadTree is similar to kd-Tree.